# Firefox's Pinned Tabs in Safari

Tags: safari, firefox

Is there a way to mimic Firefox's Pinned Tabs in Safari on Yosemite?

I love the Pinned tabs in Firefox because they allow me to easily keep a few key tabs (webmails, calendar, todo list) open without them taking up too much space. But I love Safari because it syncs with all my other devices.

I tried to search for extensions that do this, but was unable to find any.

Note: Pinned Tabs (or App Tabs) offer several functionalities:

1. they allow you to select tabs that should always be loaded when Firefox starts
2. these tabs are minimally represented in the tab bar
3. these tabs stick to the domain, e.g. eternal links are opened in new tabs by default
4. these tabs are difficult to close (e.g. [cmd]+W is ignored)

See this screenshot (gmail and twitter are pinned), or [the documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open)
[image: Screenshot of app tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Safari 9.0 (which is released together with El Capitan) you can now pin tabs. The icon for the pinned tabs has to be set by the developer for the website as an svg and is not the regular favicon; by default it's the first letter of the site.

You enable the pinned tab by right clicking on it and choosing "pin tab" or by dragging the tab to the left of the window.

[image: Pinning a tab]

[image: Unpinning a tab]

[source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW20)

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can really emulate this is if you create a Safari Extension for each website which you can put whatever picture you want for the buttons background. Don't think that's something really fluid in terms of work flow and realistic fixes, but trying to alter hard coded UI elements isn't easy to do for every day users.

**Note**: Creating an extension will require a developer certificate, but this is the closest option to your desired result https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/UsingExtensionBuilder/UsingExtensionBuilder.html

Comment: That is unfortunate, but thanks a bunch for the answer! :)

Comment: Its worth noting that a Safari Developer program is __free__ as opposed to $99 iOS dev program. So not a total loss to go this route @VonLion

Comment: Note: the Safari Developer Program is now merged into the single $99 Apple Developer Program, and no longer free

Answer (score -2):

[image: Safari file menu]

Safari open file as shown and scroll down to import from > Firefox and you should be good to go.

Comment: That only imports your bookmarks and history as far as I can tell, doesn't give you any new functionality?